# Query having 2 Where Clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am trying to login and want to validate username and password against the records in the database. I am not sure how to pass two Where clause

```
public Boolean login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "="
            + "'"+username+"'", KEY_PASSWORD + "="
            + "'"+password+"'", null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Am getting a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use two where clauses (I don't think that's allowed in ANSI SQL in any case), join them with the AND operator so it looks like:

```
KEY_NAME + " = '" + username + "' AND " + KEY_PASSWORD + " = '" + password + "'"
```

Comment: Untested, so don't take this as the absolute answer ;-)